# How to disable ajax nav system when call $.mobile.changePage?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have disable ajax in jquery mobile mobileinit event.
but when i use $.mobile.changePage to load page, It still use ajax to load pages.

```
......
<script src="/Templates/js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="/Templates/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
......
```

mobileinit works, just when i use $.mobile.changePage, it use ajax. I mean normal link isn't using ajax now, just when I call this function, ajax still be used

Comment: Tell me, have you placed your mobileinit block before jQuery Mobile initialization (but after jQuery)?

Comment: @Gajotres mobileinit works, just when i use $.mobile.changePage, it use ajax. I mean normal link isn't using ajax now, just when I call this function, ajax still be used.

Comment: Can you post your page example, mostly your HEAD content and at least one page example. Normally $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; should do the work.

Comment: @Gajotres I sink mobileinit before load the jquery mobile.

Comment: I got that, but unless we can see some of your code we cant help you.

Comment: are you navigating to some other `html` file or a `div` which `data-role` set to `page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with

```
$.mobile.changePage( url );
```

with $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false.

Had to use this instead.

```
window.location = url;
```